# GitLab Click to deploy boot disk size

Tags: google-compute-engine

On the Gitlab Click2Deploy in Google Compute engine, there is a Boot Disk Size field that defaults to 100gb.

However `df -h` reveals that the boot disk is partitioned to 10gb.

Is this normal, or a bug?

```
[lol@gitlab-ydzp ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        10G  2.4G  7.7G  24% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  8.2M  1.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image used to create the boot disk has a partition size of 10G. There is another 90G available in your disk as unpartitioned space. Please follow the steps described in the link below to repartition your disk: [Repartitioning a root persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repartitionrootpd)

Comment: I'm still a bit baffled by why click2deploy doesn't just grow the partition to 100GB. By default it mostly wastes space. if it's only making a 100gb disk for the speed improvements, why not just make a 10gb SSD. This at least deserves explanation.

Comment: repartitioning link is moving to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#repartitionrootpd

Comment: Update: The wordpress click to deploy makes an additional 90gb partition by default.